# Get contact image throws NPE

Tags: android, uri, android-contacts

I'm trying to get the contact's image but its always throwing NPE. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
Uri u = getPhotoUri(data.get(position).getContactID());
            Log.d("adapter", u.toString() + " uri");
            if (u != null) {
                holder.image.setImageURI(u);
            } else {
                holder.image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            }
```

and the method:

```
private Uri getPhotoUri(String ID) {
        try {
            Cursor cur = activity.getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + ID + " AND "
                            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='"
                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null,
                    null);
            if (cur != null) {
                if (!cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    return null; // no photo
                }
            } else {
                return null; // error in cursor process
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long
                .parseLong(ID));
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(person, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    }
```

Comment: which line is throwin´?

Comment: @eduyayo on this one `Log.d("adapter", u.toString() + " uri");`, but the selected contact do have a image

Comment: One wrong thing is that you should add a finally block closing the cursor. But anyway. The user you´re searching returns an open cursor and `moveToFirst()` returns true?

Comment: check u.toString(), whether u is null or not

Comment: it is null indeed. nothing else in that line would throw the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change your code to

```
Uri u = getPhotoUri(data.get(position).getContactID());

            if (u != null) {
            Log.d("adapter", u.toString() + " uri");
                holder.image.setImageURI(u);
            } else {
                holder.image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            }
```

It seems `u.toString()` is throwing the exception